# Loaded swf doesn't appear when referencing one of its control by string

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have in main:

```
var MyLoader:Loader = new Loader();
    MyLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, finishLoading);
    MyLoader.load(new URLRequest("MySWF.swf"));         
    MyZone.addChild(loader);
```

And in MySWF:

```
    this["aSlider"].addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE,OnSliderChange);
```

then MySWF doesn't show up on stage whereas with

```
    aSlider.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE,OnSliderChange);
```

it does appear.

I need to use this["aSlider"] because of this

http://blog.ickydime.com/2008/07/as3-notes-automatically-declare-stage.html

as pointed by https://stackoverflow.com/users/562566/ascension-systems to my previous question.

Comment: I read through your blog post regarding `this["aSlider"]` but I don't see how auto declaring of stage items would effect the above problem. If 'aSlider' exists on the stage, whether you name it, or if the Flash IDE names it, it should be accessible by it's name. Could you trace out, in the child, `aSlider`, preferably where the event listener is.

Comment: What about `this.getChildByName()` ?

Comment: thanks Kodiak but not sure what you mean. To @chris and others could you look at src  http://www.filesonic.com/file/585226724/src-slim.zip thanks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're turning off 'automatically declare instances', then you must declare the slider as a public property in your class, named the same as your stage instance.  So in mySWF.as, add this after your private variable declarations:

```
public var slider:Slider;
```

The instance exists on the stage, but it must be declared before it can be used.  Try to avoid the `myClass['myObject']` notation as it will reduce the error checking and code completion capabilities of editors like Flash Builder and FDT.